# Finding latitude and longitude in ios8

Tags: ios, ios8.3

I want to find the latitude and longitude of location in ios8 and display it in the label. I have added the "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" property in info.plist. I have turned on the location settings for this particular app.But even then it is not updating the label.No logs are working too. My code is as follows:-

```
 @IBAction func clicked(sender: UIButton) {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        let locat = locations[0] as! CLLocation
        latitude.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: locat.coordinate.latitude)
        longitude.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: locat.coordinate.longitude)
    }
```

Comment: Can't see where do you initialize your `locationManager`. Do you somewhere?

Comment: let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager is class property declared at top.

Answer (score 1):

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
```

Your locations:[AnyObject]! actually is an [CLLocation] just get its last object and use CLLocation's coordinate property.

## Complete Solution

add **CoreLocation.framework** to BuildPhases -> Link Binary With Libraries

import **CoreLocation** to your class - probably ViewController.swift
add **CLLocationManagerDelegate** to your class decleration
Add **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** and **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** to plist
init location manager:

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
get User Location By:

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation
    let long = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    let lat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    //Do What ever you want with it       
}
```

i.e Add in your plist file.,

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription = Request permission to use location service when the apps is in background.
```

[image]

## if you Are using Simulator then see you have to create one Location.GPX File To get Lat Long of Location.

> Create new file Named As "Location.GPX"

[image]

[image]

-> Add your Static Lat Long for testing Purpose.

as given Below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode"> 

    <wpt lat="23.0271480" lon="72.5085160">
         <name>Ahmedabad</name>
    </wpt>
</gpx>
```

then

-> Go to Xcode -> Edit Scheme -> Select Location.GPX File and Rubn project Again..

[image]

Comment: That method is not getting called at all. I even tried to put log there.

Comment: r u testing in Device or Simulator ?

Comment: I have completed all these steps.Is there something else that i need to do with the simulator which I am missing.I am testing in simulator.

Comment: I think it can be tested on simulator. Go to debug option while your app is running and turn on location.Turn on the gps in Settings->Privacy.(As per my knowledge, It wil not give you actual location but stored value just for testing purpose.)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out.

Comment: @KeshavRaj, if you find help in my answer, then please upvote it.

Comment: By default simulator points to no location. In order to simulate it for a location go to iOS Simulator->Debug->Location and then choose any of the last four options. See if its working or not.

Comment: @Mehul I have upvoted but it seems that I have less than 15 points here so it is not visible publicly. just the tick mark is showing

Comment: @KeshavRaj, ok np. keep coding dost. :-)

Comment: @Mehul Now when Testing on simulator is over and the app is complete I want to use real gps co-ordinates. But it is showing that added .gpx file value.How to get rid of it.

Comment: @KeshavRaj, what u want ?

Comment: @Mehul I want to use actual value. I have connected the phone and while checking the updated latitude and longitude value by running the app in iphone, I am still getting that added .gpx file value.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to keep in mind along with solution given by Mehul is not toloose reference to your CLLocationManger() object.

> func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)

It is asynchronus and if you loose reference to your lCLLocationManger() object then it won't get called and you will not get the location even after doing after everything right.